# Naming my classes and class folders in PHP project

Tags: php, naming, project-structure

I am working on an (PHP) application where users have so called workspaces. A workspace is a folder with a specific structure and bunch of specific files - user information and some workspace metadata is stored in the DB. To separate the concerns I split all classes into those which access the database and those who access the filesystem. From the technological view I think this makes perfekt sense and miimizes dependencies.

Now my structure looks like this:

```
application
|- classes
|-- dao
|--- dbAccess.class.php
|--- dbConfig.class.php
|--- dbInitializer.class.php [extends dbAccess]
|--- dbAdmin.class.php [extends dbAccess]
|--- ...more db related classes
|-- workspace
|--- wsController.class.php
|--- wsInitializer.class.php [extends wsController]
|--- wsValidator.class.php [extends wsController]
|--- ... more fs related classes
|-- exception
|--- ...exception classes
|-- ... more categories
|- test
...
...
```

But now I wonder now if my naming of the classes and class folders could be imporved:
- Is `DAO` the right category for database-using classes or does that imply for example a spefiic architecture of the class?
- Is is clever to name the other category `workspace` instead of `filesystem`? Semantically thinking `workspace` is correct - since the workspaceValidator for example validates the structure of a workspace folder and its files not the filesystem in general. On the other hand - `DAO` or `DCconnection` contains functions to access workspace metedata (which belongs sematically to the workspace) but also other data from the DB like user data. So one category is labeled after a concept from my application - workspace - and the other after technology - db - that seems a little bit weird.

I hope my problem is somehow understandable without knowing the classes themselves. Maybe someone have a good suggestion how to name them properly?

Comment: `ws` and `db` prefixes and `.class` suffixes are really redundant and annoying and this was used a lot many years ago, fortunately today not quite so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more intuitive to name areas by function first. For example

```
/areas/feature1
/areas/feature1/models
/areas/feature1/data-access
/areas/workspace
/areas/workspace/data-access
```

There are two main reasons, one it doesn't require the observer to know that the workspace feature is implemented on a filesystem. Two, it tends to remain this way longer, it's still going to be the workspace feature long after you moved to S3 buckets for storage.

Here's a [similar discussion](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7), it's for angular. but I think it tries to solve a similar problem.

It's tempting to group into technology areas, but really it can create a big headache down the road in particular if you need to split up anything. Having said that, there is more than one way to structure a project, so picking a direction and following it consistently can be more important that picking the perfect solution.